# How to implement iter method using static/dynamic dispatch?

Tags: rust, dispatch

I need to implement the method `iter`, which returns something which implements the trait `Iterator<Item = char>`. But the return value will be different implementations, depending on the enum variant.

Something like this:

```
pub enum Class {
    SingleChar(char),
    Range(Range),
    And(Vec<Class>),
    Or(Vec<Class>),
}

impl Class {
    pub fn iter(&self) -> Iterator<Item = char> {
        match *self {
            Class::SingleChar(c) => vec![c],
            Class::Range(ref range) => range.iter(),
            Class::And(ref classes) => {
                let iter: Option<_> = classes.iter().fold(None, |iter, &class| {
                    match iter {
                        None => Some(class.iter()),
                        Some(iter) => Some(iter.merge(class.iter())),
                    }
                });
                Box::new(iter.unwrap())
            },
            Class::Or(ref classes) => {
                let iter: Option<_> = classes.iter().fold(None, |iter, &class| {
                    match iter {
                        None => Some(class.iter()),
                        Some(iter) => Some(iter.interleave(class.iter())),
                    }
                });
                Box::new(iter.unwrap())
            },
        }
    }
}
```

`range.iter()` returns a struct that implements `Iterator<Item=char>`.

`merge` and `interleave` are [`itertools`](http://bluss.github.io/rust-itertools/doc/itertools/trait.Itertools.html) methods, which return `MergeAscend` and `Interleave` respectively (both of them implement `Iterator<Item=char>`)

1. How to implement such a scheme using static dispatch?
2. If static dispatch is not possible, how to implement such a scheme using dynamic dispatch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to do it using static dispatch. There is a [tracking RFC issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/518) on unboxed abstract return types, but Rust is not there yet (and I'm not sure if it could cover the use case of returning different types). Therefore, dynamic dispatch is the way to go.

You're pretty close, actually. Just make the return type `Box<Iterator<Item=char>>` and add more boxing:

```
pub fn iter(&self) -> Box<Iterator<Item=char>> {
    match *self {
        Class::SingleChar(c) => Box::new(Some(c).into_iter()),
        Class::Range(ref range) => Box::new(range.iter()),
        Class::And(ref classes) => {
            let iter: Option<_> = classes.iter().fold(None, |iter, &class| {
                match iter {
                    None => Some(Box::new(class.iter())),
                    Some(iter) => Some(Box::new(iter.merge(class.iter()))),
                }
            });
            iter.unwrap()
        },
        Class::Or(ref classes) => {
            let iter: Option<_> = classes.iter().fold(None, |iter, &class| {
                match iter {
                    None => Some(Box::new(class.iter())),
                    Some(iter) => Some(Box::new(iter.interleave(class.iter()))),
                }
            });
            iter.unwrap()
        },
    }
}
```

This should work.